# Why does pool run the entire file multiple times?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to understand the output from this Python 2.7.5 example script:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', time.localtime(time.time())))
props2=[
            '170339',
            '170357',
            '170345',
            '170346',
            '171232',
            '170363',
            ]
def go(x):
     print(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=3)
    pool.map(go, props2)

print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', time.localtime(time.time())))
```

This yields the output:

> 2015-08-06 10:13
>
> 2015-08-06 10:13
>
> 2015-08-06 10:13
>
> 170339
>
> 170357
>
> 170345
>
> 170346
>
> 171232
>
> 170363
>
> 2015-08-06 10:13
>
> 2015-08-06 10:13
>
> 2015-08-06 10:13

My questions are:

A)  Why does the time print three times at the beginning and the end?  I would have expected it to print the start time, and then the end time.

B)  The real question - How do I get it to run one command multiple times, but all the others a single time?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Python imports the `__main__` module for each process. On an import, the whole file is executed again. On python 3, if you remove the `if __name__ == '__main__'` you will get an infinite loop since the file is getting recursively called.

For the real question:

In python scripts, I typically try to avoid executing any statements or variables on the global scope except for function definitions. I use the below as a template for all python scripts.

```
import sys

def main(argv):
  #main logic here

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

When you have a script with re-usable functions, even if it has a main method, you can import it into another script if you need to.

Comment: For me it doesn't, if I remove the `if` statement it executes fine, also printing the times only once. And in a subprocess the module's name would be `__main__` as well, wouldn't it?

Comment: On python 3, the removal of the `if` will cause a problem. On python 2.7, it doesn't. The subprocess module changes the `__name__` variable on the import. With the multiprocessing module, if there are not enough cores, it is not going to execute on X number of processes. On a small vm with just 2 cores, the OP's code doesn't replicate for me. On my laptop with 8 cores, the above issue replicates just fine.

Comment: @LelandBarton sometimes we use `import filename` to execute a script within our current script. E.g., I have a situation where I scrape a website with a different script every time I run my primary script. In that situation, where would you recommend placing `import filename`? Perhaps, within the if __name__=='main' conditional prior to calling main()?

Answer (score 5):

Multiprocessing needs to import your script in each subprocess in order to use the `go()` function.  When your script is imported, it prints the date.  If you only want something to run in the main script, put it in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.

Answer (score 2):

The modification presented below won't print those lines multiple time.

```
import time

from multiprocessing import Pool

def main():
  if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', time.localtime(time.time())))
  props2=[
        '170339',
        '170357',
        '170345',
        '170346',
        '171232',
        '170363',
        ]

  pool = Pool(processes=3)
  pool.map(go, props2)

  print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', time.localtime(time.time())))

def go(x):
  print(x)

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your original post had indenting wrong for:

```
print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', time.localtime(time.time())))
```

All "global" statements are run for each process.