# Python Multiprocessing outside of main producing unexpected result

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a program that makes a call to an API every minute and do some operations, when some condition is met, I want to create a new process that will make calls to another API every seconds and do some operations. Parent process doesn't care the result that this child process produce, the child will run on its own until everything is done. This way the parent process can continue making call to the api every minute and doing operations without interruption.

I looked into multiprocessing. However I cant get it to work outside of **main**. I tried passing a callback function, but that created unexpected result (where parent process starting running again in parallel at some point).

Another solution I can think of is just create another project, then make a request. However then I will have a lot of repeated code.

What is the best approach to my problem?

example code:

```
class Main:
    [...]
    foo = Foo()
    child = Child()

    foo.Run(child.Process)
    


class Foo:
    [...]
    def Run(callbackfunction):
        while(True):
            x = self.dataServices.GetDataApi()
            if(x == 1020):
                callbackfunction()
                #start next loop after a minute
    

class Child:
    [...]
    def Compute(self):
        while(True):
            self.dataServics.GetDataApiTwo()
            #do stuff
            #start next loop after a second

    def Process(self):
        self.Compute() # i want this function to run from a new process, so it wont interfer
```

Edit2: added in multiprocess attempt

```
class Main:

    def CreateNewProcess(self, callBack):
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            p = Process(target=callBack)
            p.start()
            p.join()
        
    foo = Foo()
    child = Child(CreateNewProcess)

    foo.Run(child.Process)
    


class Foo:
    def Run(callbackfunction):
        while(True):
            x = dataServices.GetDataApi()
            if(x == 1020):
                callbackfunction()
            #start next loop after a minute
    

class Child:
    _CreateNewProcess = None

    def __init__(self, CreateNewProcess):
        self._CreateNewProcess = CreateNewProcess

    def Compute(self, CreateNewProcess):
        while(True):
            dataServics.GetDataApiTwo()
            #do stuff
            #start next loop after a second

    def Process(self):
        self.CreateNewProcess(self.Compute) # i want this function to run from a new process, so it wont interfer
```

Comment: multiprocessing is a good approach. For details about your problem with it you should show the relevant code properly formatted in the question.

Comment: Code outside the main check is run for each process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858352/why-does-pool-run-the-entire-file-multiple-times

Comment: @MichaelButscher Hey, I have just added a sample code. Can you give me some advice? Should I add my attempt to use multiprocess? it doesnt work so I dont want to confuse

Comment: In your "Main" class you create instances and call a method on one. This should be done only very carefully outside of the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard which is described in the Python docs about multiprocessing. I think it shouldn't be done here. You should show how you try using multiprocessing. It is the right approach and it should be possible to fix your problem with it.

Comment: @MichaelButscher thanks for the reply. I just added my attempt at the multiprocessing on the example code. I created a callback for creating a new process in main, then just pass it into child class so it can use it. But I think due to the reason Mike67 mention, this wont work. I tried turning daemon on but still not working, I am at lost, please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reorganize a few things. Among others:

- The guard `if __name__ == '__main__':` should include creation of
  objects and especially calls to functions and methods. Usually it is
  placed on the global level at the end of code.
- Child objects shouldn't be created in main process. In theory you can
  do this to use them as containers for necessary data for the child
  process and then sending them as parameter but I think a separate
  class should be used for this if seen as necessary. Here I used a
  simple `data` parameter which can be anything pickleable.
- It is cleaner to have a function on global level as process
  target (in my opinion)

Finally it looks like:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class Main:
    @staticmethod
    def CreateNewProcess(data):
        p = Process(target=run_child, args=(data,))
        p.start()
        p.join()


class Foo:
    def Run(self, callbackfunction):
        while(True):
            x = dataServices.GetDataApi()
            if(x == 1020):
                callbackfunction(data)
            #start next loop after a minute


class Child:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def Compute(self):
        while(True):
            dataServics.GetDataApiTwo()
            #do stuff
            #start next loop after a second



# Target for new process. It is cleaner to have a function outside of a
# class for this

def run_child(data):   # "data" represents one or more parameters from
                       # parent to child necessary to run specific child.
                       # "data" must be pickleable.
                       # Can be omitted if unnecessary
    global child
    child = Child(data)
    child.Compute()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()

    foo.Run(Main.CreateNewProcess)
```